# Advice on resetting Mongock Changesets

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mongock

We are using Mongock in our spring-boot/kotlin microservices as our main Mongo DB migration tool and it is working perfectly. We started with a simple json file to create a few collections and have been adding changesets for a while now.

By now we have so many changesets that it is becoming hard to see what 'the truth' is about our database. We do not have one single json file or a bunch of files which tells us what the state of the database is, it is an accumulation of the start json and all changesets.

I would like to create a new baseline script based on the current situation and start over.
What are some best-practices to achieve this? Of course without losing data etc.

Comment: What is your intention with the baseline? Because I have the impression we may have different understanding of what this operation entails. 

Are you after  a kind of solution that shows the state because you don't have visibility over your changes and therefore it's hard to know the current state of your migration?

If you had an easy way to visualise the state of your migration(lets say the state operation), would you still require the baseline. 

Or are you expecting something that can ignore all existing changeUnits in code as a baseline operation - and therefore won’t apply these?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My intention is to clean up the changesets and start fresh but without data-loss of course. So, when you're a developer and start up the service for the first time, it should run the 'baseline' script and build the database for you. 
When you have an existing db already it should skip the baseline part, also in production, it should skip this part. 
So, I just with to have a clean start with changesets, starting from a new 'baseline'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking two different things. First **How to know the current state of the Mongock migrations**, and second, **How to perform a baseline**

1. **How to know the current state**

Mongock offers a cli(currently in beta, although is pretty stable) which offers this.

Simple running `./mongock state db -aj yourApp.jar`
Currently it requires passing your application jar, but this dependency will be removed.

More information in the documentation.

- [CLI page](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/cli/index.html)
- [CLI operations page](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/cli/operations/index.html)
- [State operation section](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/cli/operations/index.html#state-db-pro)
- [Springboot example readme](https://github.com/mongock/mongock-examples/tree/master/mongodb/springboot-quickstart)

2. **Baseline**

Mongock currently doesn't provide this feature in the CLI, but it's one of the next items in our roadmap

Comment: Thank you once again. I'll give it a try with the CLI. Its just hard to see what the actual state of the database structure is without going through all the changesets.